# WiX Bootstrapper: Rollback notification

Tags: wix, wix3.6, burn

In the bundle.wxs of my managed bootstrapper, I have chained multiple packages:

```
<Chain>
  <ExePackage Id="Test1"......>
  <ExePackage Id="Test2"......>
  <ExePackage Id="MicrosoftVCPP2005Redistributable" SourceFile="..\Tools\VC2005Redistributable\vcredist_x86.exe" Vital="yes"   InstallCondition="SelectedDBSize1 = 24" />
</Chain>
```

I'm subscribing to the `ExecutePackageBegin`/`ExecutePackageComplete` events to check which package is currently being executed and accordingly display the progress text indicating which installation is in progress.

But, if due to some reason a roll back action starts midway, I want to change the progress text to indicate that rollback is in progress. Is there any event available when there is a switch from installation to rollback? Or do I have to check the sequence of the packages being invoked and decide based on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for the property is a little bit wrong but the `ExecutePackageBeginEventArgs` class's `ShouldExecute` property will tell you if the package is being "executed" or "rolled back".  In your case, when the `ExecutePackageBeginEventArgs.ShouldExecute=false` then you know that package is being rolled back.